# POST http://localhost:3000/api/signup/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

i am trying to send data of the user from react to express and use the create function to create a new user
but is says error 404 and page not found
why?

my api endpoint (found in client/src/components/api-users :

```
async function create (data) {
  try {

    const resp = await fetch('/api/signup/' , { //error initiating here
        method:'POST',
        mode:"cors",
        credentials:'include',
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json ',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          "Access-Control-Origin": "*"
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(data)
      })
    console.log(resp)

    console.log(resp.body)
    resp.headers.forEach(console.log);

    return JSON.stringify(resp);
  } catch (err) {
       console.log(err)
    }
}



    export {
      create

    }
```

my user controller for signup:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var atob =require('atob')
var Cryptr = require('cryptr')
var cryptr = new Cryptr('q1w2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9p0p0o9i8u6y5t4r3e2w1q')
var db  =require('../server')
const create = (req, res, next) =>{      
     first_name  = req.body.first_name,
     last_name = req.body.last_name,
     username =req.body.username,
     password= req.body.password,
     email=req.body.email,
     dec_pass =atob(toString(req.body.password)),
     encrypted_pass =cryptr.encrypt(dec_pass)

    var sql = "INSERT INTO `user`(`user_id`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`username` , `email`,`password`) VALUES ('','" + first_name + "','" + last_name + "','" + username + "','" +email+ "','" +encrypted_pass+ "')";
    var query = db.query(sql, function(err, result){
       console.log(query)
      console.log(req)
       return (JSON.stringify(result));
    });
};

  export 
  { create }
```

server js file for db connection:

```
var  Sequelize = require('sequelize')
var app = require('./app')
var CONFIG= require('../config/CONFIG')
const db = {}


const sequelize = new Sequelize ("users" , "root" , "" ,{

        host:'localhost',
        dialect:'mysql',
        operatorAliases:false,

        pool:{
            max:5,
            min:0,
            acquire:30000,
            idle:10000
        }

})

console.log(CONFIG.db_host)
db.sequelize=sequelize
db.Sequelize=Sequelize
console.log('alright')
export default db
```

mu user routes :

```
const express           = require('express');
const router            = express.Router();
var userCtrl = require ('../controllers/user.controller')
router.post('/signup', userCtrl.create) 
module.exports = router
```

my signupjs react file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {create} from './api-user.js'

class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      username:'',
      first_name:'',
      last_name :'',
      email : '',
      password :''

    }

  this.clickSubmit = this.clickSubmit.bind(this)
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log("nextProps", nextProps);
}

 componentDidMount(){
console.log("Component did mount")
  }



handleChange = e => {
  if (e.target.name === "username") {
    this.setState({ username: e.target.value });
  }
  if (e.target.name === "first_name") {
    this.setState({ first_name: e.target.value });
  }
  if (e.target.name === "last_name") {
    this.setState({ last_name: e.target.value });
  }
  if (e.target.name === "email") {
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
  } if (e.target.name === "password") {
    this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
  }
}

clickSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
 const data = this.setState({
    first_name  :this.state.first_name,
    last_name : this.state.last_name,
    username : this.state.username,
    password:this.state.password,
    email:this.state.email,
})
create(data) //i dnt know if this correct or not 
}
```

Comment: where is the `api` coming from in your request URL? Your route on express just seem to be on `/signup` (from what you posted).

Comment: @tpschmidt yes it is /signup , i tried api/signup but it didnt work

Comment: What I meant: If you did not configure the `api` prefix for your express router in some other file, you have to go for `/signup` and not `/api/signup` in your POST request.

Comment: @tpschmidt this is the github repo , i beg your help https://github.com/ghadi1998/finallog.git

Comment: @tpschmidt i am on deadline and i passed it , i really could get fired if i dont do this , help me please

Answer (score 1):

As @Deep Kakkar mentioned you don't set an `api` prefix so you should find `/signup` working instead of `/api/signup`

also `fetch(/api/signup)` will hit this relative path on your current domain (where react app is up on), you need to set full path instead, for instance, if your `http-server` is up on port `4000` and your react app is up on `3000` then you should fetch `http://localhost:4000/api/signup` not `/api/signup` as this will be `http://localhost:3000/api/signup`

Comment: i put /signup in the express router .. router.post(/signup , userCtrl) but aso i didnt get any thing , i also put the  complete path but nothing there

Comment: I cloned your repo and tried to check what might be wrong,
**server**
- first I got import error with `config` changed it to be `var CONFIG= require('./../config/config')` in both `app.js` & `server.js`

**client**
- Imported your implemented `create` in `Signup` and invoked it in `clickSubmit` with hard-coded object
- In `api-user.api` changed `url` on line #6 to be `'http://localhost:5000/signup/'`, also commented line #9 `credentials: :'include'`
- Now i get `500` from express with this error `Error: "value" required in setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value)`

Comment: Now you can access `api` from your react app but check your implementation what might be wrong also it's better to use `axios` instead of `fetch`

Answer (score -1):

**Localhost:3000/api/products 404 Error**
You did not create res.get("/api/products") on server.js or you did not set the proxy. check below for proxy setting.

**Proxy error: could not proxy request /api/products**
Check this:

1. frontend/package.json

   {
   "name": "frontend",
   "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
   ...
   }
2. stop running frontend and backend
3. Run backend first

   npm start
4. Then frontend

   cd frontend
   npm start

Comment: But I did, I even tried with Postman and it worked fine